# Splitting the list

Tags: java, regex, excel, apache-poi

I have two questions regarding the splitting of any ArrayList.

1. one of my list empdetails is returning this `["Employee","Emp Name","Emp Sex","Emp Address"]` - If you see this this actually a list of size 1, so even if I iterate this list it will give me only value and when I am trying to write this list in excel it is writing "Employee","Emp Name","Emp Sex","Emp Address" in one cell. Is there any way to write Employee, Emp Name etc in different cells?
2. My second list "fieldValues" which contains the values of Employees is something like this: `["5001", ,, "Emp Test", ,, "Male", ,, "Texas", "5002", ,, "Emp Test 1", ,, "Female", ,, "WV"]`: I want to insert Emp 5002 in second row of excel. The only way I think of is to check the single delimiter which is coming after "Texas" but not sure how to do that.

Code for second question :

```
String[] tempValue = new String[fieldValues.size()];
int j = 0;
for (Object valueInfo : fieldValues){
    String [] fieldInfo = ((String)valueInfo).split(",");
    if(fieldInfo.length > 0){
        tempValue[j] = fieldInfo[0];
    }
    j++;
}
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Are you using any excel libraries for doing this like jexcel, poi,..?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your **first question**,
       You should remove braces on the value and split based on semi colon delimiter, then you can write into different cells.

**For Second question:**
   I assume the number of columns in each row is fixed, that way variable 'j' increment till your last column in each row, then insert a new line and reset your counter. Here you should use the split the below way to count even if the column values are empty

```
 String [] fieldInfo = ((String)valueInfo).split(",", -1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got the answer of my first question but couldnt get for second question. variable 'j' is incrementing till the end of the list. And I want to insert the new row after "Texas"

Comment: You should not increment till end of the list. Say each row contains 10 columns, increment j value for each iteration and check if j==10.If so, you know you reached end of the row, start inserting new row by resetting j to 0

Comment: Yeah that's right, but columns in each row is not fixed.

Comment: Ho god..Then no other way except urs..but i feel the upstream should consider sending the proper way to indicate the end of the row.